# Minecraft 1.17.1 OptiFine how to solve OpenGL error?

Tags: java, opengl, minecraft

Problem: When I join Minecraft, OpenGL errors 1280 and 1282 appear
and update graphic driver and reinstall Minecraft 1.17.1, OptiFine
but I can't solve this problem ;(

version: 1.17.1

OptiFine: optifine 1.17.1 G9

Shader: complementaryshaders 4.0.2v

OpenGL version : 4.6

[latest.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4qaQ.png)

[latest.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u8Du.png)

[latest.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iaP6.png)

[OpenGL version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psj5l.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't experiencing any actual graphical issues, OpenGL errors are unfortunately kind of normal with OptiFine.  I may be slightly off on the exact wording, but you can turn off the error messages under:

Settings > Video Settings > Other > Show OpenGL errors.

If you are experiencing issues beyond the error text, post your full log somewhere?

Comment: [latest log](https://ufile.io/o9z75d8s) frame drop occurs

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of Complementary Shaders?  It looks like we're at 4.2.2 now.

Comment: I updated the shader but it still occurs errors

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two things to solve this issue:

1. Update ComplementaryShaders to the latest version (v4.2.2)
2. If the issue still persists, attempt using Iris Shaders instead of OptiFine (This was mentioned in the ComplementaryShaders Project Page)

Comment: This is good, but I want to control shader settings without mod

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by that? You need to use either OptiFine or Iris to load ComplementaryShaders, as stated by their Project Page.

Comment: This option [image](https://imgur.com/a/kQmA1Ht)
Iris Shaders doesn't have this button